# Verify set theory formula

Tags: matrices, algorithms

i'm trying to develop an algrothim that takes in 2 matrices and calculates a score based on unique elements in the matrices.

High level steps:

1. Take matrices A and B, convert them into vectors, then into sets
2. Divide the cardinality of the intersection of A and B by the maximum cardinality  of A or B

I currently write the formula as such:

$$
SS(A,B)=\frac{\mathrm{card}(\theta(\mathrm{vec}(A))\cap\theta(\mathrm{vec}(B))}{\mathrm{max}(\mathrm{card}\big(\theta(\mathrm{vec}(A))\big),\mathrm{card}\big(\theta(\mathrm{vec}(B))\big))}
$$

```
A = [[ 1  1  2],   B = [[ 1  1  3],   C =  [[ 3  4  3]
     [ 1  2  3],        [ 1  1  5],         [ 3  3  4]
     [ 2  3  4]]        [ 1  5  3]]         [ 1  3  2]]
```

The answers should be:

```
SS(A,B) = 0.8
SS(A,C) = 1.0
```

Have i expressed the formula for SS in correctly? Is there another formula that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably come up with a name for the function

$$f(A, B) := \frac{|A \cap B|}{\max(|A|, |B|)} = \min\left(\frac{|A \cap B|}{|A|}, \frac{|A \cap B|}{|B|}\right)$$

I'd probably also write the set of elements of a matrix $A$ as $\{a_{ij}\}$ or something of the sort rather than as $\theta(\operatorname{vec}(A))$.

So then you could just write

$$SS(A, B) := f(\{a_{ij}\}, \{b_{k\ell}\}).$$

But first I think I'd consider why I'm looking at the set of entries of a matrix in the first place.  It seems like a weird thing to look at in most cases.

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was after. The set entries are matrices as they are the output of a image segmentation model. I'll be using the algrothim to score predictions from the model.